# How to add DOM elements instantly from inside a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, dom

here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do :

```
let num = 10000;
function recursive() {
    if (num > 0) {
        let p = document.createElement('p');
        p.textContent = num;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
        num --;
        recursive();
    }
}
```

This code creates paragraph elements and add them to my html after the entire function has completed. But what if I want to instantly append them as I am going with other procedures of the function?

I know, this might be a bit silly. But I really need this to display the current progress of the function in the html page. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can emulate progress like this

```js
let num = 1000;
function recursive() {
    if (num > 0) {
        let p = document.createElement('p');
        
        let t = num;
      
        setTimeout(() => {
          p.textContent = t;
          document.body.appendChild(p);
        }, t*100)


        num --;
        recursive();
    }
}
```

---

Comment: This indeed shows the paragraphs one after another. But it starts outputting after the entire recursion completes (which is even worse)

Comment: I haven't any ideas, but maybe it will help you [Avoid Large, Complex Layouts and Layout Thrashing](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing)